# Import angular controller webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack

I use `webpack` with my AngularJS webapp project.

```
import routing from './config';
 import connection from 'E:/Workspace/Mbisvn/quiky-frontend/app/modules/connection/web-connector.js';

var app = angular.module('app', [
uirouter, sanitize, cookies, resource, ngUpload, connection,
  uiBt, loadingBar
]);

app.controller("LoginCtrl", LoginCtrl);
```

But I have error `LoginCtrl is not defined` when I declare `app.controller("LoginCtrl", LoginCtrl);`

And this is my LoginCtrl script (login-ctrl.js)

```
var LoginCtrl = ['$scope', '$log', '$state', 'webConnectorService',
function($scope, $log, $state, webConnectorService) {

$scope.webConnectorService = webConnectorService;
$scope.init = function() {

};

$scope.getUserProfile = function() {

};

$scope.init();

}];
```

I don't know how to import login-ctrl.js file in webpack to solve this error. Thanks for the help.